# Basic C++ question from a novice programmer

Tags: c++

I am a novice C++ programmer and am trying to work on a school lab. Below, I have pasted the shell of a program that I am working on. In main, I am instantiating the object `car1` which belongs to the `class Velocity`. When I try to use this instantiation with the function `mpsConverter`, I get an error indicating that the expression must have a class type. We have done similar examples in class and this format worked fine. Any ideas? If this is not the appropriate forum for simple questions like this, please point me in the right direction to a more appropriate one.

Thanks, Al

```
// P1_2.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "conio.h"
using namespace std;

class Velocity
{
    private:
        int mpsInput;       // input value: meters per second (mps)
        int kmphInput;      // input value: km per hour
        int mphOutput;      // output value: comverted value of km per hour to miles per hour (mph) 
    public:
        int kmphOutput;     // output value: converted value of mps to km per hour
        Velocity();             
        void mpsConverter(int speedKmph);
        void mphConverter();
        ~Velocity();
};

Velocity::Velocity()        // Constructor
{
    cout << "The initial is text is displayed when an object in the class Velocity is Instantiated." << endl;
}

void Velocity::mpsConverter(int speedKmph)      // convert KM per hour into meters per second (mps)
{
    kmphOutput = (speedKmph * 2); 
}

void Velocity::mphConverter()       // convert KM per hour into miles per hour (mph)
{

}

Velocity::~Velocity()       // Destructor
{

}

int main()
{
    Velocity car1();
    car1.mpsConverter(2);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Velocity car1();
```

The above statement isn't creation of an instance `car1` of type `Velocity`. You are trying to <s>call</s> declare a function `car1()` whose return type is `Velocity`. Since there is no instance created -

```
car1.mpsConverter(2); // This statement is giving you error stating mpsConverter(2)
                      // can only be called on class types.

Velocity car1 ; // This is the right way of instance creation.
```

Comment: Thank you, I will make the changes and continue on.

Comment: Actually, no function is called. The statement Velocity car1(); declares a function car1 of type Velocity ().